# Contextualizing SVGs with HTML / CSS when using <use>

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to reuse a particular SVG file within an HTML template. To keep my template legible and the SVG props configurable via CSS I'm utilizing the 'use' element to pull the SVG in externally.

Css Tricks gives a nice tutorial on how to use the  element:
http://css-tricks.com/svg-use-external-source/

My predicament is that I need to reuse this SVG in several places and want to give each group different properties like colors, stroke, etc... However, it doesn't appear that I can create any type of context when using 'use', such as wrapping it with a 'div' and then trying to stylize the SVG based on that context.

**EXAMPLE**
http://jsfiddle.net/pathsofdesign/3bob8rat

**HTML**

```
<div class="Boxes-1">
    <svg version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height"100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <g id="box-group">
            <g id='box-1'>
                <rect width="100" height="100" />     
            </g>
            <g id='box-2'>
                <rect x="25" y="25" width="50" height="50" />     
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>

<div class="Boxes-2">
    <svg version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100" height"100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">    
        <!-- Pull in #box-group set from SVG above -->
        <use xlink:href="#box-group"></use>
    </svg>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#box-1 {
    fill: red;
}

/* Does Work */
#box-group #box-2 {
    fill: blue;
}

/* Does NOT Work */
.Boxes-2 #box-group #box-2 {
    fill: purple !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `use` (because of the way the deep cloning takes place) you can only apply CSS selectors to the original element's children and all the applied styles get also cloned. However, you can not apply any CSS selectors to the clone and its children.

from [**http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement**](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement):

> *CSS2 selectors can be applied to the original (i.e., referenced) elements because they are part of the formal document structure. CSS2 selectors cannot be applied to the (conceptually) cloned DOM tree because its contents are not part of the formal document structure.*

You can however use **inheritance** to somehow get around the problem.

> *Property inheritance, however, works as if the referenced element had been textually included as a deeply cloned child of the ‘use’ element. The referenced element inherits properties from the ‘use’ element and the ‘use’ element's ancestors. An instance of a referenced element does not inherit properties from the referenced element's original parents.*

So for the style that you want to apply in all the clones you use CSS selectors on the original content (e.g. `#box-1` gets always a red `fill`) and for the changing elements apply the style to the including elements (parents) and have it be inherited to the included elements (e.g. `#box-2` can then inherit different fills from the parents). For example with something like this:

```
#box-1 {
    fill: red; /* gets applied to the original and all clones */
}  
.Boxes-1 {
    fill: green; /* will be inherited by the original #box-2 */
}
.Boxes-2 {
    fill: purple; /* will be inherited by the cloned #box-2 */
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/3bob8rat/4/)

Comment: This seems like a huge limitation with the `<use>` tag. I need to style `svg`s differently based on where they are in the page - the same exact path can appear in different places but need different colors. I don't expect that that is an uncommon situation but I wont be able to use `use` because of this limitation.